# Iteratively shift variables in data

Tags: r, dplyr

Some example of my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
df <- tibble(
    v1 = c(1:6),
    v2 = rnorm(6, 5, 2) %>% round,
    v3 = rnorm(6, 4, 2) %>% round,
    v4 = rnorm(6, 4, 1) %>% round %>% lag(1),
    v5 = rnorm(6, 6, 2) %>% round %>% lag(2),
    v6 = rnorm(6, 5, 3) %>% round %>% lag(3),
    v7 = rnorm(6, 5, 3) %>% round %>% lag(4))

     v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7

1     1     3     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     2     6     3     3    NA    NA    NA
3     3     7     3     4     4    NA    NA
4     4     0     2     5    11     3    NA
5     5     6     3     4     6     1     8
6     6     6     2     3     5     7     4
```

I want to shift it by diagonal, that separates NA and filled data. 
So, desired output looks like this:

```
     v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7

1    NA    NA     3     3     4     3     8
2    NA     3     3     4    11     1     4
3     1     6     3     5     6     7    NA
4     2     7     2     4     5    NA    NA    
5     3     0     3     4    NA    NA    NA
6     4     6     2    NA    NA    NA    NA
7     5     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
8     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Each column around v3 is just shifted by 1, 2, 3.. etc rows down and up.

Tried to achieve this inside `dplyr::mutate_all()` but I failed to iterate it with a `lag()` and `lead()` functions.

EDIT: after @wibeasley advice I made this

```
df %>% 

    mutate(dummy1 = c(3:8)) %>% 
    gather("var", "val", -dummy1) %>% 
    mutate(
        dummy2 = sub("v", "", var, fixed = T),
        dummy3 = dummy1 - as.numeric(dummy2) + 1) %>% 
    select(-dummy1, -dummy2) %>% 
    spread(var, val) %>%
    slice(-c(1:4)) %>% select(-dummy3)
```

Looks ugly, but works.

Comment: How do you know to change each column's length to 8 from 6?

Comment: It may be easier to do this as a matrix, instead of a data.frame.  I'm a big tidyverse fan, but as you're finding, dataframe-based approaches don't comfortably shift values up/down (*i.e.*, across rows).  If you want a dataframe approach and lead/lag don't work well, consider using tidyr to go longer/taller to shift values, and then transform it wider at the end.

Comment: @r2evans I dont want to miss my nonNA data, so if it shifts to rows 7 and 8, I need to add 2 more. Probably I could do it in advance, just filling my data with dummy NA rows.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to handle each column, putting `NA` to the back.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
df
# # A tibble: 6 x 7
#      v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     3     3     4     3     8
# 2     2     6     3     4    11     1     4
# 3     3     7     3     5     6     7    NA
# 4     4     0     2     4     5    NA    NA
# 5     5     6     3     3    NA    NA    NA
# 6     6     6     2    NA    NA    NA    NA
```